# Remove duplicate record based on condition from xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

If a record with duplicate **Emplid** is coming in input xml then i want to delete a record which is having **status** as 'withdrawn'. I want to only keep the record whose status is active if record with same emplid coming twice.

Input xml

```
<Recordset>
<Record>
    <Emplid>10001</Emplid>
    <name>Bob Dylan</name>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <status>active</status>
    <year>1985</year>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Emplid>10002</Emplid>
    <name>Bonnie Tyler</name>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <status>withdrawn</status>
    <year>1988</year>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Emplid>10001</Emplid>
    <name>Bob Dylan</name>
    <country>Uk</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <status>withdrwan</status>
    <year>1975</year>
</Record>
</Recordset>
```

expected xml

```
Recordset>
<Record>
    <Emplid>10001</Emplid>
    <name>Bob Dylan</name>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <status>active</status>
    <year>1985</year>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Emplid>10002</Emplid>
    <name>Bonnie Tyler</name>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <status>withdrawn</status>
    <year>1988</year>
</Record>
</Recordset>
```

Appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: XSLT - 
While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**: 
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its version.

Comment: The rules as you have stated them are incomplete. What should happen when the same `Emplid` has 2 or more `withdrawn` records (but no `active` records)? Is it correct to assume that there can be at most one `active` record per `Emplid`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k one Emplid will have max. one active and one withdrawn record, there wont be any scenario where one Emplid is having 2 withdrawn record. Also in case if only withdrawn record is present then we dont have to make any changes.

Comment: So basically you want to copy all active records, and also any withdrawn records that do not have an active record with the same Emplid?

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So basically you want to copy all active records, and also any withdrawn records that do not have an active record with the same Emplid?

> yes exactly

Well, then why not do exactly that:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="act" match="Record[status='active']" use="Emplid" />

<xsl:template match="/Recordset">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Record[status='active']"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Record[status='withdrawn'][not(key('act', Emplid))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you want to keep the original order, you can combine the two `xsl:copy-of` instructions into one:

```
        <xsl:copy-of select="Record[status='active'] | Record[status='withdrawn'][not(key('act', Emplid))]"/>
```

---

Note the use of a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to resolve cross-references.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following XSLT.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Record[status='withdrawn']">
        <xsl:variable name="Emplid" select="./Emplid"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(/Recordset/Record[Emplid=$Emplid]) &gt; 1">
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(/Recordset/Record[Emplid=$Emplid]) = 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```